# Fill in values between start and end value in R

Tags: r

W (blue line below) in my data.frame represents where the water level in the river intersects the elevation profile.

[image]

In my data.frame, for each group in ID, I need to fill in values between the start and end value (W)

My data

```
> head(df, 23)
   ID elevation code
1   1       150 <NA>
2   1       140 <NA>
3   1       130    W
4   1       120 <NA>
5   1       110 <NA>
6   1       120 <NA>
7   1       130    W
8   1       140 <NA>
9   1       150 <NA>
10  2        90 <NA>
11  2        80 <NA>
12  2        70 <NA>
13  2        66    W
14  2        60 <NA>
15  2        50 <NA>
16  2        66    W
17  2        70 <NA>
18  2        72 <NA>
19  2        68    W
20  2        65 <NA>
21  2        60 <NA>
22  2        68    W
23  2        70 <NA>
```

I want the final result to look like below

```
   ID elevation code
1   1       150 <NA>
2   1       140 <NA>
3   1       130    W
4   1       120    W
5   1       110    W
6   1       120    W
7   1       130    W
8   1       140 <NA>
9   1       150 <NA>
10  2        90 <NA>
11  2        80 <NA>
12  2        70 <NA>
13  2        66    W
14  2        60    W
15  2        50    W
16  2        66    W
17  2        70 <NA>
18  2        72 <NA>
19  2        68    W
20  2        65    W
21  2        60    W
22  2        68    W
23  2        70 <NA>
```

I tried many things but my trials were not successful. Your help will be appreciated.

**DATA**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), elevation = c(150L, 
140L, 130L, 120L, 110L, 120L, 130L, 140L, 150L, 90L, 80L, 70L, 
66L, 60L, 50L, 66L, 70L, 72L, 68L, 65L, 60L, 68L, 70L), code = c(NA, 
NA, "W", NA, NA, NA, "W", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "W", NA, NA, "W", 
NA, NA, "W", NA, NA, "W", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

Comment: can you please tell us how you decide start and end ? I mean in your example, why cant row 7 be start and row 13 be end?

Comment: row 3 is the start for ID1 and row 7 is the end for ID1. For ID2, row 13 is the start, row 16 is the end. Row 19 is the start and row 22 is the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(code = coalesce(code, c(NA, "W")[cumsum(!is.na(code)) %% 2 + 1]))

   ID elevation code
1   1       150 <NA>
2   1       140 <NA>
3   1       130    W
4   1       120    W
5   1       110    W
6   1       120    W
7   1       130    W
8   1       140 <NA>
9   1       150 <NA>
10  2        90 <NA>
11  2        80 <NA>
12  2        70 <NA>
13  2        66    W
14  2        60    W
15  2        50    W
16  2        66    W
17  2        70 <NA>
18  2        72 <NA>
19  2        68    W
20  2        65    W
21  2        60    W
22  2        68    W
23  2        70 <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a helper function that creates a sequence between each start and end and assigns `'W'` to it.

```
assign_w <- function(code) {
  inds <- which(code == 'W')
  code[unlist(Map(seq, inds[c(TRUE, FALSE)], inds[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))] <- 'W'
  code
}
```

and apply it for each `ID` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(result = assign_w(code)) %>%
  ungroup

#   ID elevation code result
#1   1       150 <NA>   <NA>
#2   1       140 <NA>   <NA>
#3   1       130    W      W
#4   1       120 <NA>      W
#5   1       110 <NA>      W
#6   1       120 <NA>      W
#7   1       130    W      W
#8   1       140 <NA>   <NA>
#9   1       150 <NA>   <NA>
#10  2        90 <NA>   <NA>
#11  2        80 <NA>   <NA>
#12  2        70 <NA>   <NA>
#13  2        66    W      W
#14  2        60 <NA>      W
#15  2        50 <NA>      W
#16  2        66    W      W
#17  2        70 <NA>   <NA>
#18  2        72 <NA>   <NA>
#19  2        68    W      W
#20  2        65 <NA>      W
#21  2        60 <NA>      W
#22  2        68    W      W
#23  2        70 <NA>   <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(water_flag = (1 * !is.na(code)) * if_else(elevation < lag(elevation, default = 0), 1, -1),
         water = if_else(cumsum(water_flag) == 1, "W", NA_character_))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try `replace` + `cumsum`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(code = replace(code, cumsum(!is.na(code)) %% 2 == 1, "W")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 23 x 3
      ID elevation code
   <int>     <int> <chr>
 1     1       150 NA
 2     1       140 NA
 3     1       130 W
 4     1       120 W    
 5     1       110 W
 6     1       120 W
 7     1       130 W
 8     1       140 NA
 9     1       150 NA
10     2        90 NA
# ... with 13 more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

First I tried to use `fill` but had no success. Then I learned here about the benefit of R's recycling property [Rename first and second occurence of the same specific value in a column iteratively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157438/rename-first-and-second-occurence-of-the-same-specific-value-in-a-column-iterati/67157472#67157438) (Thanks to Ronak!)

```
# prepare data with renaming `start` and `stop` sequence
df$code[is.na(df$code)] <- "NA"
df$code[df$code == 'W'] <- c('start', 'end')
df$code[df$code=="NA"]<-NA

# Now with different names of start and stop sequence I was able to implement `cumsum`
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(code))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(code = replace(code, first(code) == 'start', 'W'),
                code = replace(code, code=='end', 'W')) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 23 x 3
      ID elevation code 
   <int>     <int> <chr>
 1     1       150 NA   
 2     1       140 NA   
 3     1       130 W    
 4     1       120 W    
 5     1       110 W    
 6     1       120 W    
 7     1       130 W    
 8     1       140 NA   
 9     1       150 NA   
10     2        90 NA   
11     2        80 NA   
12     2        70 NA   
13     2        66 W    
14     2        60 W    
15     2        50 W    
16     2        66 W    
17     2        70 NA   
18     2        72 NA   
19     2        68 W    
20     2        65 W    
21     2        60 W    
22     2        68 W    
23     2        70 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is similar to @Onyambu's: create an 'index' (ind) that increases by one each time a non-NA is encountered in the 'code' column. If the index value is divisible by 2 (i.e. it is an even number) insert "NA" into the new column. If the index is not divisible by 2, add a "W" into the new column. Then if there is a "W" in the 'code' or 'new' columns, replace the NA in the 'code' column with W and drop the 'new' column from the dataframe.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ind = ifelse(cumsum(!is.na(code)) %% 2 == 0, NA, "W")) %>% 
  mutate(code = ifelse(ind == "W" | code == "W", "W", NA)) %>% 
  select(-c(ind))

#>   ID elevation code
#>1   1       150 <NA>
#>2   1       140 <NA>
#>3   1       130    W
#>4   1       120    W
#>5   1       110    W
#>6   1       120    W
#>7   1       130    W
#>8   1       140 <NA>
#>9   1       150 <NA>
#>10  2        90 <NA>
#>11  2        80 <NA>
#>12  2        70 <NA>
#>13  2        66    W
#>14  2        60    W
#>15  2        50    W
#>16  2        66    W
#>17  2        70 <NA>
#>18  2        72 <NA>
#>19  2        68    W
#>20  2        65    W
#>21  2        60    W
#>22  2        68    W
#>23  2        70 <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Though the question has been marked as solved(answer accepted) yet for further/future reference, there is a function `fill_run` in library `runner` which does exactly this.

`fill_run` replaces `NA` values if they were surrounded by pair of identical values.  Since our additional requirement is to look at `elevation` too we can do something like this

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(code = runner::fill_run(ifelse(!is.na(code), paste(elevation,code), code), only_within = T))

# A tibble: 23 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
      ID elevation code 
   <int>     <int> <chr>
 1     1       150 NA   
 2     1       140 NA   
 3     1       130 130 W
 4     1       120 130 W
 5     1       110 130 W
 6     1       120 130 W
 7     1       130 130 W
 8     1       140 NA   
 9     1       150 NA   
10     2        90 NA   
# ... with 13 more rows
```

Needless to say, you can again `mutate` non-NA values from `code` to `W` very easily, if required.